# vite + React + @mempool/mempool.js when build got something error

Tags: reactjs, vite

For vite(5.0) + React(18.0) projects, use yarn add @mempool/mempool.js. However, an error is reported in the console after packaging
[image]
[image]

The running is normal, and problems occur only after run yarn built. And I don't know why, so all helps are appreciated.